# What is the difference between OpenAI and ChatOpenAI in LangChain?

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I read the LangChain [Quickstart](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart).

There is a demo inside:

```py
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

llm = OpenAI()
chat_model = ChatOpenAI()

llm.predict("hi!")
>>> "Hi"

chat_model.predict("hi!")
>>> "Hi"
```

I searched the rest of the document and also online, but didn't find any info for the difference between OpenAI and ChatOpenAI.

Based on `from langchain.llms import OpenAI`, OpenAI is a large language model (LLM) which is also chat related.

So is OpenAI more general-purpose, while ChatOpenAI more chat focused?

What is the difference between `OpenAI` class and `ChatOpenAI` class in LangChain? Could someone clarify?

Comment: Take a look at here, might answer your question: https://www.reddit.com/r/LangChain/comments/12fhkrj/what_is_the_difference_between_using_chatopenai/

Comment: maybe just different models there are so much models, llms means large language models, chat_models just chat

Comment: Thanks @OMiShah, however that question is asking `ChatOpenAI` vs chains, instead of `ChatOpenAI` vs `OpenAI`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## TL;DR

Based on my research,

- `OpenAI` class includes more generic machine learning task attributes such as `frequency_penalty`, `presence_penalty`, `logit_bias`, `allowed_special`, `disallowed_special`, `best_of`.
- `ChatOpenAI` class provides more chat-related methods, such as `completion_with_retry`, `get_num_tokens_from_messages` to make it more user-friendly when build chatbot related applications.

---

## Class Inheritance

Upon reviewing the source code, here's what I've discovered.

Listed below are the class inheritances for both the `OpenAI` and `ChatOpenAI` classes, along with their respective class attributes and methods.

#### OpenAI

[OpenAI](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/34088107481a029b60bc6dd166770e80ff72fadd/libs/langchain/langchain/llms/openai.py#L615-L615) ← [BaseOpenAI](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/34088107481a029b60bc6dd166770e80ff72fadd/libs/langchain/langchain/llms/openai.py#L134-L134) ← [BaseLLM](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/34088107481a029b60bc6dd166770e80ff72fadd/libs/langchain/langchain/llms/base.py#L157-L157) ← [BaseLanguageModel](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/34088107481a029b60bc6dd166770e80ff72fadd/libs/langchain/langchain/schema/language_model.py#L49-L49)

[image: OpenAI]

#### ChatOpenAI

[ChatOpenAI](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/34088107481a029b60bc6dd166770e80ff72fadd/libs/langchain/langchain/chat_models/openai.py#L119-L119) ← [BaseChatModel](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/34088107481a029b60bc6dd166770e80ff72fadd/libs/langchain/langchain/chat_models/base.py#L52-L52) ← [BaseLanguageModel](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/34088107481a029b60bc6dd166770e80ff72fadd/libs/langchain/langchain/schema/language_model.py#L49-L49)

[image: ChatOpenAI]

## Comparison

Let's begin our comparison, moving from the fourth column to the first column.

#### Fourth Column

Both classes ultimately inherit from the base class `BaseLanguageModel`.

#### Third Column

`BaseLLM` and `BaseChatModel` are very similar with slightly difference:

- For OpenAI's `BaseLLM`, it includes additional methods:

  - `batch(self, inputs, config=None, max_concurrency=None, **kwargs)`
  - `abatch (self, inputs, config=None, max_concurrency=None,**kwargs)`
- For ChatOpenAI's `BaseChatModel`, it includes an extra method:

  - `_combine_llm_outputs(self, llm_outputs)`

#### Second Column

The second column contains the `BaseOpenAI` class, which primarily exists due to the presence of higher-level classes `OpenAI` and `AzureOpenAI`. However, they all share the same class attributes and methods.

#### First Column

At the top-level class (first column):

- `OpenAI` class includes more generic machine learning task attributes such as `frequency_penalty`, `presence_penalty`, `logit_bias`, `allowed_special`, `disallowed_special`, `best_of`.
- `ChatOpenAI` class provides more chat-related methods, such as `completion_with_retry`, `get_num_tokens_from_messages` to make it more user-friendly when build chatbot related applications.